# Running WebView in Background

Tags: android, android-webview, android-service, android-networking

I am developing an application which utilizes a WebView to sign into a website, pull content from it, then notify the user when content is updated.  I have gotten the WebView to get the content however I need to know how I can run the WebView as Service in order to get it to run in the background.

As I understand, WebViews must be manipulated from the UI thread which makes things a whole lot harder.

Any suggestions/workarounds as to how I can get the app to notify the user regardless of whether they have the app open or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While WebViews need to be manipulated on a single thread it doesn't necessarily need to be the UI thread (unless you want to attach the WebView to the view hierarchy), however it needs to be the same thread for all of the WebViews.

While it's not something explicitly supported (or heavily tested) there is nothing special that the WebView does to prevent you from running it in a Service. The WebView does call a couple of methods on the Context that don't normally work in a Service (like getTheme()), so you'd have to work around that with a ContextWrapper. You'll also need to manually call `WebView.layout` to trick the WebView into thinking it has a size. There might be more stuff you'd need to do, but nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=359#c7 if you're having crashes with HTML select dialogs.

Comment: This does not appear to be true any longer - seems like it _must_ be the UI thread. When I try to create a WebView in another thread I get: "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'UtilityWebViewServiceThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads."

Comment: Working for me, specially the "WebView.layout()" manual call. I'm creating the webview from an intentservice, thanks.

Comment: MUST BE UI THREAD!

Comment: OK, so now it must be a UI thread. No big deal, we can still post a runnable to UI thread even from a background app, and all runs fine. But how to create a WebView with a service context, without creating an activity, or a transparent, zero size window (which needs SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, which I want to avoid...) Some outline of Java or Kotlin code would be appreciated...

Comment: @gregko "But how to create a WebView with a service context". Service context still has a `looper` so it shouldn't be a problem for WebView to be initialized in a context that has a looper. If that causes any problem give the next solution a try. Get application context in your Service and pass it to the WebView constructor as a context. Both solutions should work as expected, I have created a WebView with application context but not with Service context, so I'm a bit hesitant about the validity of the solution with the Service context

Comment: Thank you, @Farid! I actually figured it out and I'm using it in my published app - a WebView created with a Service context. No complaints from over 500,000 active users monthly.

Answer (score 2):

You mean that?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            ... something 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inflate or modify any view from background thread. But if you want the content of a web page, you can fetch it in a background thread using HTTP GET. You need to use GET on the url to get its HTML data.

Answer (score 0):

It will check if it is possible to have a WebView instance running and control it programmatically to load a page without it having to occupy the screen during page loading. Then when you know you have material loaded I will want to switch to its display in an instant. I will do some testing to see if it can be done on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution from Ori Harel at https://medium.com/@oriharel/how-to-run-javascript-code-in-a-background-service-on-android-8ec1a12ebe92:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    ...

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId{

        
        final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                      | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        params.width = 0;
        params.height = 0;

        final WebView wv = new WebView(this);

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                Log.d("Error","loading web view: request: "+request+" error: "+error);
            }

            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                
                if (request.getUrl().toString().contains("/endProcess")) {
                    
                    windowManager.removeView(wv);

                    wv.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            wv.destroy();
                        }
                    });
                    stopSelf();
                    return new WebResourceResponse("bgsType", "someEncoding", null);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
        wv.loadUrl(bgsUrl);
        windowManager.addView(wv, params);
    }

    ...
}
```