# Android WebView stops JavaScript execution after 5 minutes when app in the background

Tags: java, android, webview

The following code loads a URL into my WebView and executes JavaScript every 5 seconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        myWebView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                myWebView.loadUrl("URL");
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

When the app is put into background (and even the display is off) the WebView keeps loading the URL indefinitely however after 5 minutes JavaScript execution stops.

I have tested this behavior by logging each GET request on the server and having JavaScript on the website make a GET request that gets logged separately.

Turning off the battery optimization for the app itself and the System WebView does not work in solving this issue.

Can a WebView keep executing JavaScript indefinitely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running WebView in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674635/running-webview-in-background)

Comment: @MorrisonChang unfortunately not. Provided answers are not sufficient enough to aid me in solving the JavaScript problem.

Comment: I was thinking of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68354848/295004) and the linked article therein, although the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#system-alert) permission may have additional steps/restrictions. Do realize that [Android's Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) will suspend your app, WebView included. So how you are testing is a factor as well.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I tried to call `myMainActivity.myWebView.loadUrl(...)` from a background sticky notification service without luck.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Have you resolved yet?